# Multiply two ranges in Excel to get an array result

Tags: arrays, excel, range, excel-365

Excel 365 allows to multiply ranges to get an array as a result.

Example:

| # | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| **2** | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Entering in A3
`= A1:C1 * A2:C2`

will evaluate to `{1,0,1} * {0,1,1}`

and return an array `{0,0,1}` spilling in `A3:C3`

| # | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **3** | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This operation can also be used in formulas, especially useful in `FILTER()`, `SUMPRODUCT()` etc.

Is there a formula in Excel 365 that can take as arguments an arbitrary number of 1-D ranges, multiply them, and return a 1-D array in the same way as above?

For what I found out so far, `SUMPRODUCT()` and `MMULT()` can return only a single value, not a  1-D array.

Alternatively, I can write a `LAMBDA`, but would like to avoid it, if there is a ready-made formula for it.

Comment: It will be {2,0,0,1}, not {3,0,0,1}. BYCOL could do what you mean. REDUCE could result in the same and can result in 2D arrays.

Comment: @p.b I think OP is talking about row numbers in that first column. That said, Reduce would be a great option. Some sample data will be nice.

Comment: And MMULT definately can return an array.

Comment: Correct, First column is Excel row nums for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% what do you mean, I would assume you want to multiply all rows of the same column and return a row array with the result per column. You can achieve it in cell `E1` using the following formula:

```
=BYCOL(A1:C3, LAMBDA(col, PRODUCT(col)))
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**If you have only positives numbers**, then you can use `MMULT`, based on the following mathematical properties:

[image: log properties]

Putting in excel terms using `EXP/LN` functions in our case it would be:

```
=EXP(MMULT(TOROW(ROW(A1:C3)/ROW(A1:C3)), LN(A1:C3)))
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetitions:

```
=LET(rng, A1:C3, rows, ROW(rng), u, TOROW(rows/rows), EXP(MMULT(u, LN(rng))))
```

You get the same result.

**Note**: `rows/rows` just returns the unit vector with the same number of rows as `A1:C3`.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce range multiplication, using *a single built-in formula*. The first example is perhaps the closest to it, except it assumes a continuous range of vectors - which can be done via HSTACK() or VTACK(). Anyway, thank you for laying it all out, I think it closes the question.